# Mapping an attractive Yukawa potential to Square Well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, scattering

I would like to understand how is possible to map an attractive Yukawa potential $(g/r) e^{-a*r} $ where g and a are some constants,  to a finite potential well potential in consistent way. Thanks!

Comment: well, it can be done if the volume of the potential can be taken  equal to the square well or any other form say exponential and the binding energy of say deuteron is calculated..then equivalent potentials  can be found..a guess